Robot Capture the flag
Two robots, Aaron and Erin, have made it to this year’s final! Initially they are situated at the center of a unit circle. A flag is placed somewhere inside the circle, at a location chosen uniformly at random. Once the flag is placed, Aaron is able to deduce its distance to the flag, and Erin is only able to deduce its direction to the flag. (Equivalently: if $(r, \theta)$ are the polar coordinates of the flag’s location, Aaron is told $r$ and Erin is told $\theta$.)
Both robots are allowed to make a single move after the flag is placed, if they wish. Any move they make is without knowledge of what the other robot is doing. (And they may not move outside the circle.)
Whichever robot is closer to the flag after these moves captures the flag and is declared the winner!
During the preliminaries it was discovered that Erin is programmed to play a fixed distance along the detected angle θ. Assuming otherwise optimal play by both robots, can you determine the probability that Aaron will win? (Please express your answer to 10 decimal places.)
My approach:
It is given the Erin is programmed to play a fixed distance, I took that Erin fixed distance to be zero for ease of solving (This might be wrong).
So now Aaron has to pick $\theta$ now the distance between Aaron point and actual point would be $2r\sin(\theta/2)$. The distance between Erin and Flag is $r$. So we need to calculate the probability of event
$2r\sin(\theta/2)<r \implies \sin(\theta/2) < \frac{1}{2}$.
Can someone help me out in my approach? Is there any flaw or wrong assumption?

(For reference, this is Jane Street's puzzle of the month, April 2024 https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/archive/ )

You may not assume that Erin's fixed distance is 0. You are told the Erin plays optimally, and almost certainly moving 0 is not optimal. Is moving 1/2 optimal?

When $r=0$ then $\theta$ is undefined.

Now, there is an answer provided by Jane Street: https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/robot-capture-the-flag-solution/

I feel like I may have misunderstood the question so please tell me if I have done so.
Firstly, it is reasonable to find what the optimal strategies actually are for Erin and Aaron.
Since Erin knows the value of $\theta$, she wants choose a value $x$ such that the distance between herself at $(x,\theta)$ and the flag at $(r,\theta)$ is minimised. Let $R$ be the distance of the flag from the origin, let $f(r)$ be the PDF of $R$ and let $F(r)$ be the CDF. Since we are working with a circle of radius $1$, by comparing areas we can see that $$F(r)=\mathrm{P}(R\le r)=\frac{\pi r^2}{\pi}=r^2$$Differentiating gives $f(r)=2r$. We want to minimise the expected distance from $(x,\theta)$ to $(r,\theta)$, which is $\lvert r-x\rvert$. This is $$\begin{align}\mathrm{E}(\lvert R-x\rvert)&=\int_0^12r|r-x|\,\mathrm{d}r\\&=\int_0^x2r(x-r)\,\mathrm{d}r+\int_x^12r(r-x)\,\mathrm{d}r\\&=x^3-\frac23x^3+\frac23-x-\frac23x^3+x^3\\&=\frac23x^3-x+\frac23\end{align}$$It can clearly be seen through differentiation that $\mathrm{E}(|R-x|)$ is minimised when $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, so Erin's strategy is to place herself at $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\theta\right)$.
WLOG Let Aaron place himself at $(y,0)$, where $0\le y\le1$. By the cosine rule, the expected distance from $(y,0)$ to $(r,\theta)$ is $\sqrt{r^2+y^2-2ry\cos\theta}$. Since $\theta$ is uniformly distributed between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, $$\mathrm{E}\left(\sqrt{r^2+y^2-2ry\cos\theta}\right)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sqrt{r^2+y^2-2ry\cos\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$This integral does not involve elementary functions but using a graphing calculator this is minimised when $y=0$, so Aaron's optimal strategy is to place himself at the origin.
Considering the two aforementioned strategies, it is only possible for Aaron to win if $r<\frac1{2\sqrt2}$. The probability of this happening is $\mathrm{P}\left(R<\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)=\frac18=\boxed{0.125}$.

Thank you for for answer, but I have a question about the best strategy of erin.
Is strategy(minimize the expected distance) =  strategty(beat Aaron), if so can we prove it?

Given that Erin doesn't know about Aaron's move the strategy to capture the flag should be to get as close to the flag as possible. Please note that I submitted this answer and it doesn't look like I got it right.

Since Erin knows the angle, it seems you should be using another probability measure than $P(R\le r)$ when it comes to determining $E(|R-x|)$. It might have to do with a-priori/a-posteriori/Bayesian distributions.

@mickeyandkaka you might be right. If Erin knows that Aaron's best strategy is to place himself at the origin then she can to place herself infinitesimally from the centre, in which case Aaron will not win, so $p=0$?

@Sai Mehta I got some information from that the answer is larger than 0.125 (however I do not know the answer), but I can not find any problem on your analysis. I think it is because the strategy is different.

I think the initial strategy from the other solution is correct, but it's possible to update Aaron's strategy to improve his probability of winning somewhat. I'm not completely sure that my calculation of this is correct, but I think I have the right idea.
I'll briefly reiterate the other solution here for completeness. Let's say the flag's true location is at a point $(r,\theta)$. Let us also describe Erin's move as $(r_E, \theta_E)$ and Aaron's move as $(r_A, \theta_A)$.
Since Erin will always pick a fixed distance along the angle she is given, we can calculate what the optimal choice of this fixed distance is. Using a distance of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we can see that the 'inner circle' created by this radius has an area of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, which is equivalent to half the area of the entire unit circle. Thus, choosing this distance functionally divides the area in half, and it is equally likely for the flag to be in the 'outer ring' or the 'inner circle' created by this division. So given the true angle $\theta$, Erin will always choose to move to $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \theta\right) = (r_E, \theta_E)$.
Then, we want to figure out Aaron's optimal strategy. He simply needs to get closer to $(r, \theta)$ than Erin, and he might consider the same logic as Erin, that he can 'divide' the space in halves with equal probability of the flag being in each. If he figures that Erin is always sitting at $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \theta\right)$, he knows that he will always be closer to the flag than Erin if the flag's distance $r$ is less than half the distance from the origin to Erin's position. Specifically, if the flag's distance $r < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, Aaron will always beat Erin. Hence, if $r < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, Aaron will always choose to stay at the origin $(0,0)$.
Now, this is where the other solution ends. If this is Aaron's only strategy, then he has a $\frac{1}{8}=0.125$ chance of winning, since the flag's distance $r < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ $\frac{1}{8}$ of the time (we can see this by noticing that the circle of radius $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ has area $\frac{1}{8}\pi$, which, divided by the entire unit circle's area $\pi$, is $\frac{1}{8}$).
HOWEVER, it is actually possible for Aaron to perform better than this strategy if he changes his strategy depending on his knowledge of what $r$ is. As I mentioned before, Aaron knows he will always win if $r < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. Similarly, Aaron knows he will always lose if $r > \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. Hence, in these cases, it is beneficial for him to try moving anywhere else besides the origin, since he cannot have a lower chance of winning than he already does ($0$).
In order to beat Erin, Aaron simply needs to be closer to the flag than Erin is. Geometrically, this space can be described as a circle surrounding the flag with radius equivalent to $r_E - r$. We know that $r_E$ is always going to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so this radius is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - r$.
Thus, if Aaron knows both the true radius, $r$ and the optimal radius for Erin to choose, $r_E$, he can 'slice' the unit circle and restrict his move to the distance range where he knows this 'circle' will be. If $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} < r < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, the distance range he chooses will be
\begin{align}
\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - 2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-r\right), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] = \left[2r - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right]
\end{align}
If $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < r < 1$, the distance range he chooses will be \begin{align}
\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, r + \left(r - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] = \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 2r - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right]
\end{align}
(Note that if the reasoning for the above is not clear, it's difficult to explain well without using a diagram -- I might try to add a picture to this later, but I suggest you draw it out and mark where the 'edge' at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is, and draw hypothetical 'circles' around the flag at different points with a radius spanning the distance from the flag to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, then measure the distances you would need to 'slice' the unit circle so that it touches the outer edges of this circle. There might also be a cleaner way to write this, I'm not sure.)
With this updated strategy, now, Aaron has a slight chance of winning in cases where $r > \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, which is equivalent to the area of the 'circle' with radius $|r_E-r|$ divided by the area of the 'slice' Aaron chooses. This part of the calculation is where I'm not quite sure if I did it correctly but here goes. We can see that Aaron's probability of winning given his new dynamic strategy goes something like this:
\begin{align}
P[\text{A wins}] &= P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,r<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right]P\left[r<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right] \\
&+ P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}<r<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right]P\left[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}<r<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] \\
&+ P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right]P\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right]
\end{align}
The probability of Aaron winning in any given distance condition is equivalent to the amount of that space in which he wins, divided by the total amount of space in that 'slice'. Then, the probability of $r$ being within any of these particular parameters is equivalent to the area of the space where $r$ meets those conditions, divided by the area of the total unit circle, which is $\pi$. Let's go over it in more detail.
We already know that
\begin{align}
P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,r<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right]P\left[r<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right] = 1 \cdot \frac{\pi}{8}\pi = \frac{1}{8},
\end{align}
since as mentioned before, Aaron will always win in this case.
Now, let's look at the case where $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}<r<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Let's call this slice 1. Then, we want to find the area of this slice, $A_{s1}$, and the area of the 'circle' within it in which Aaron wins, $A_{c1}$. As described before, the probabilities we want to find are
\begin{align}
P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}<r<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] &= \frac{A_{c1}}{A_{s1}} \\
P\left[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}<r<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] &= \frac{A_{s1}}{\pi}
\end{align}
Since $r<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we know that the radius of our circle $|r_E - r| = \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - r\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - r$. Thus,
\begin{align}
A_{c1} &= \pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-r\right)^2 \\
&= \pi\left(r^2-\sqrt{2}r+\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
Then, to get the area of the slice, we take the area of the circle with the larger radius and subtract the area of the circle with the smaller radius in the given radius range.
\begin{align}
A_{s1} &= \pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 - \pi\left(2r-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 \\
&= \pi\left(\frac{1}{2} - 4r^2 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}r - \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
&= \pi\left(2\sqrt{2}r - 4r^2\right) \\
&= \pi\left(4r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-r\right)\right)
\end{align}
Note that since we ultimately want $P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,r<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right]P\left[r<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right] = \frac{A_{c1}}{A_{s1}}\frac{A_{s1}}{\pi} = \frac{A_{c1}}{\pi}$, it appears that we do not actually need to calculate $A_{s1}$ for our answer, but I am doing so just to demonstrate for slice 1 to help with the reader's understanding. We can jump ahead like so:
\begin{align}
P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,r<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right]P\left[r<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right] &= \frac{A_{c1}}{\pi} \\
&= \frac{\pi\left(r^2-\sqrt{2}r+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\pi} \\
&= r^2-\sqrt{2}r+\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
We can calculate the probabilities in the remaining slice, where $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1$, in a similar way. Call this slice 2, with the of this slice being $A_{s2}$ and the area of our winning 'circle' we need to hit $A_{c2}$. Then:
\begin{align}
P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right] &= \frac{A_{c2}}{A_{s2}} \\
P\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right] &= \frac{A_{s2}}{\pi} \\
P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right]P\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right] &= \frac{A_{c2}}{A_{s2}}\frac{A_{s2}}{\pi} = \frac{A_{c2}}{\pi}
\end{align}
similarly to before.
Calculate $A_{c2}$:
\begin{align}
A_{c2} &= \pi\left(r-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
&= \pi\left(r^2 - \sqrt{2}r + \frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
Taking a shortcut again, we can quickly see that
\begin{align}
P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right]P\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right] = r^2 - \sqrt{2}r + \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
similarly to the case for slice 1.
Now, obviously these are not "real" probabilities, as they still depend on the value of $r$. This is the point at which I'm fairly confident I am mathematically correct, but I'm not sure at which point in my notation I went wrong as to miss this part. We need to integrate over the range of $r$ for each of the two slices to obtain an actual probability that does not depend on any unknowns. I think it has to do with CDF vs. PDF, but I'm admittedly not super well versed on the differences beyond mathematical intuition. If anyone could advise me on how to correct my notation so there isn't just an awkward jump at this step, let me know. But anyway, now we integrate for slice 1:
\begin{align}
P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right]P\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right] &= \int^{1/\sqrt{2}}_{1/2\sqrt{2}} \left(r^2 - \sqrt{2}r + \frac{1}{2}\right)dr \\
&= \left[\frac{1}{3}r^3 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}r^2 + \frac{1}{2}r\right]^{1/\sqrt{2}}_{1/2\sqrt{2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{48\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}
Then, we do the same for slice 2:
\begin{align}
P\left[\text{A wins}\,\middle|\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right]P\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<r<1\right] &= \int^{1}_{1/\sqrt{2}}\left(r^2-\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)dr\\
&= \left[\frac{1}{3}r^3 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}r^2 + \frac{1}{2}r\right]^{1/\sqrt{2}}_{1/2\sqrt{2}}\\
&= \frac{40\sqrt{2}-56}{48\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}
We can also reformat the probability $\frac{1}{8}$ for ease of addition into $\frac{1}{8} = \frac{6\sqrt{2}}{48\sqrt{2}}$.
Then we have:
\begin{align}
P[\text{A wins}] &= \frac{6\sqrt{2}}{48\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{48\sqrt{2}} + \frac{40\sqrt{2}-56}{48\sqrt{2}} \\
&= \frac{6\sqrt{2}+1+40\sqrt{2}-56}{48\sqrt{2}} \\
&= \frac{46\sqrt{2}-55}{48\sqrt{2}} \\
&\approx \boxed{0.1481}
\end{align}
This probability of Aaron winning is better than the previous probability of $0.125$, so this strategy is better.
Note that I don't know if this is the absolute best solution out there -- I suspect there might be a way to optimize even further by splitting into more slices by halving the distances again and checking if the area of the circle on one side divided by that slice is a better probability than the other side, but I haven't checked this yet. I don't think I've made any mistakes in my calculation, but I'm open to feedback. I also know that the integrals are a bit redundant and I could have just spanned from $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ to $1$ directly and gotten the same result, but I wanted to be rigorous and show where all of it came from; if there's a way to skip there in a way that directly explains why I don't need to split the two slices, let me know.

I'm not sure why the other answer was not correct, but an alternative approach I was thinking of was to take Erin's optimal position as being at $x = \frac{1}{2}$, while Aaron's optimal position is at the origin (since any other position, though more beneficial if he moves in the correct direction, is less beneficial in equal measure if he moves in the incorrect direction, canceling out the benefit). The reasoning behind this would be that once Erin knows the angle of the flag, then the flag is equally likely to be at any point along the 'line' spanning from the origin to the edge of the unit circle at that angle. If these two strategies were indeed the most optimal strategies for each robot, then intuitively, Aaron will only win if $r < 0.25$ (since any radii above that value would be closer to Erin's position than to the origin), which has a probability of $0.0625$ of occurring.
However, I don't think this is likely to be the right approach, since it would be more likely that the flag is at a position with a larger value of $r$, since the area in that 'slice' is larger than the area of 'slices' at lower values of $r$. I feel like intuitively, it would be important to account for the fact that we are operating in a circular space, hence the breakdown in the other answer makes sense.
I also considered the possibility that if Erin knows Aaron's strategy, she can place herself at a point infinitely close to but not exactly at the origin, so that she is always closer to the flag than Aaron (unless the flag is placed at the origin), but given that the problem states "Any move they make is without knowledge of what the other robot is doing", I don't think that the two robots' strategies acknowledge each other at all. (Also, I have a feeling that that isn't the type of solution the problem is looking for, given the history of the types of puzzles Jane Street posts, but they might surprise me.)
I'm wondering if there might be some trick we're missing here that would give us a messier looking answer, since the problem says to express your answer to 10 decimal places...unless that's a red herring?
Note that I don't plan on trying to submit this answer myself since I'm not fully convinced, so I won't know if it's correct or not until the solution is ultimately posted.

The point which is infinitely close to the origin is the origin.

In this answer I tried to develop more or less rigorous approach to answer the question, but this seems to be a complicated task. My current approach is the following.
First we need to clarify the notions of a strategy and an optimal strategy. For this purpose we use the following standard approach.
Let $\mathbb D$ be the unit disk centered at the origin $O$ of the plane and $(r_A,\theta_A)$ and $(r_E,\theta)$ be the positions of Aaron and Erin, respectively, after their moves.
Suppose that for each $r\in [0,1]$ we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A_r$ on $\mathbb D$. The set $\mathbb A$ of Aaron's strategies consists of functions $\alpha$ on $[0,1]$ such that for each $r\in [0,1]$, $\alpha(r)$ a probability measure on $\mathcal A_r$ such that $\alpha(r)(X)$ is the probability of the event $(r_A, \theta_A)\in X$ for each $X\in\mathcal A_r$.
Suppose that for each angle $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal E_\theta$ on $[0,1]$. The set $\mathbb E$ of Erin's strategies consists of functions $\varepsilon$ on $[0,2\pi]$
such that for each $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$, $\varepsilon(\theta)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal E_\theta$ such that $\varepsilon(\theta)(X)$ is the probability of the event $r_E\in X$ for each $X\in\mathcal E_\theta$.
For each $\alpha\in\mathbb A$ and $\varepsilon\in\mathbb E$ let $P(\alpha,\varepsilon)$ be the probability that Aaron wins when he uses the strategy $\alpha$ and Erin uses the strategy $\varepsilon$.
Then it is natural to put
$$P(\alpha,\varepsilon)=\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \alpha(r)(X(r,\theta,r_E))r d\varepsilon(\theta) d\theta dr,$$
where $X(r,\theta,r_E)=\{(r_A,\theta_A)\in D:r_A^2+r^2-2rr_A\cos(\theta_A-\theta)<(r-r_E)^2
\}\in\mathcal A_r$ for each $r,r_E\in [0,1]$ and each $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$. Moreover, we need the integral to exist.
Aaron's ensured winning probability $P(\alpha)$ when he uses the strategy $\alpha$ is $\inf\{P(\alpha,\varepsilon):\varepsilon\in\mathcal E\}$.
The strategy $\alpha$ is optimal, if for each $\alpha'\in\mathbb A$ we have $G(\alpha)\ge G(\alpha')$.
We see that to ensure the measurability of all sets $X(r,\theta,r_E)$ it suffices to assume that for each $r\in [0,1]$ we have $\mathcal A_r=\mathcal A$, where $\mathcal A$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb D$ generated by intersections of $\mathbb D$ with open disks. It is natural to assume that there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal E$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\mathcal E_\theta=\mathcal E$ for each $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$. Then the rotation symmetry of the game suggests to consider the case when the elements of $\mathbb E$ does not depend on $\theta$. Moreover, we assume that for each $\alpha\in\mathbb A$, each $r\in [0,1]$, and each rotation $\varphi$ of $\mathbb D$ around the origin, we have $\alpha(r)(\varphi(X))=\alpha(r)(X)$ for each $X\in\mathcal A_r$. Maybe these assumptions can be justified by some averaging arguments. Under these assumptions, for each $\alpha\in\mathbb A$ and $\varepsilon\in\mathbb E$ we should have
$$P(\alpha,\varepsilon)=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \alpha(r)(X(r,0,r_E))r d\varepsilon(0) dr.$$
To be continued?

Since this question is (at the time of this answer) an ongoing challenge by Jane Street, I will only give some hints of my solutions (under different possible interpretations of the puzzle). The challenge also requires answers precise to 10 decimal places; I won't express my answers to such precision. Perhaps I shall note that I haven't submitted my answers to Jane Street, because---for reasons to be explained---I am not convinced that there is a completely well-defined answer, and because it's good to keep the suspense!
Edit: Following Hans-Peter Schrei's comment raising doubt about my initial 17.4% that Aaron beats Erin in Scenario 2, I realised I had made a mistake in my calculations of $r_E^*$: my method really yields a probability of 16.6% that Aaron beats Erin. I edited my answer to provide a bit more information on the method.
Remark. In what follows, subscripts $A$, $E$ and $F$ on variables indicate that those variables are associate to Aaron, Erin or the flag, respectively. Moreover, for conciseness, I might identify the players and their robots.
Preliminary discussion. The optimal strategies of both players depend on the knowledge/ignorance that both players have about each other's knowledge/ignorance. As a mere illustration of this fact, if Erin had any good reason when programming her robot (so apparently here, before the tournament...) to expect Aaron to play $r_A = 0$ (respectively, $r_A = 1$), then Erin (who knows $\theta_F$) would have programmed her robot to move to $\theta_E = \theta_F$ and to a distance $r_E$ from the origin that is only slightly larger than $0$ (respectively, slightly lower than $1$), as Erin would thus expect to beat Aaron with a probability only slightly less than $1$. Note that this is different from the value $r_E = 1/\sqrt{2}$ that minimises Erin's expected distance to the flag.
So the first challenge of the puzzle is to identify what Aaron and Erin know about each other's knowledge/ignorance of the situation. In my opinion, the phrasing of the puzzle is a bit too ambiguous to solve this first challenge with absolute certainty. Here are a few questions that come to mind:

It is said that Aaron's and Erin's robots are able to deduce/detect $r_F$ and $\theta_F$, respectively. This suggests that they have been engineered this way, and so we have no reason to expect Aaron to know that Erin can detect $\theta_F$ and to expect Erin to know that Aaron can detect $r_F$. (This scenario is plausible as it is said that it was 'discovered' during previous matches that Erin's robot is programmed to play a fix distance (along the detected $\theta_F$), so players seem to be initially ignorant of others' robots' capabilities.)

As a counterpoint, the puzzle also phrases this same info as Aaron and Erin being told $r_F$ and $\theta_F$ respectively. Told by whom? Their robots? The tournament's organisers? This raises the question as to whether it was known before the tournament that at each match, one player would be given $r_F$ and the other $\theta_F$.

It was discovered in preliminary matches that Erin's robot is programmed to play a fixed distance along the detected angle. What's the meaning of 'fixed' here: $\theta_F$-independent or even match-independent? What exactly has been discovered: the moving about a 'fixed distance', or even the value of this 'fixed distance', or perhaps also that Erin's robot can detect $\theta_F$? Does Aaron know about this discovery? Does Erin know that Aaron knows? Was it Erin who disclosed this information voluntarily (before the tournament) to as to make it public common knowledge?

Erin seems to have a rigid strategy (programmed in her robot before the tournament) that can't be changed from one match to another. Is it the same for Aaron, or can he adapt his strategy for this final match (based e.g. on the discovery about Erin's robot)?


Clearly there are a lot of possible scenarios. Below, I shall consider the two extreme scenarios: (1) maximal ignorance of each other's robot's capabilities, and (2) maximal common public knowledge. We shall see that these two scenarios have different optimal strategies for Aaron and Erin, the first having a little under 20% chance that Aaron beats Erin, the second having a little under 17% that this happens. Fortunately, most of the intermediate plausible scenarios lead to the same optimal strategies as those of (1), so the answer $\mathrm{Prob}(\mbox{$A$ beats $E$}) \approx 0.2$ should be taken as the most plausible.
Scenario 1: maximal mutual ignorance. We suppose that Aaron's and Erin's robots were engineered to detect $r_F$ and $\theta_F$ respectively, and that these capacilities are unknown to their opponent. We forget about the discovery concerning Erin's robot during preliminary games, and we don't assume from the start that Erin's robot is programmed to play a fixed distance along $\theta_F$.
Let $X$ be either Aaron or Erin, and $Y$ be $X$'s opponent. Since $X$ knows nothing about $Y$, it is in $X$'s best interest to suppose that $Y$ can deduce $\theta_F$: indeed, regardless of the distance $r_Y$ that $Y$ would intend to play along $\theta_Y$, the distance between $Y$ and $F$ (the flag) is minimised when $\theta_Y = \theta_F$. So if $X$ can play well/'optimally' against a $Y$ who knows $\theta_F$, $X$ will only perform better against a $Y$ who doesn't know $\theta_F$.
Now, $X$ has no reason to expect $Y$ to know anything about $X$'s capabilities, so $X$ expects $Y$ to expect $X$ to know $\theta_F$. So, although $X$ possibly doesn't know $\theta_F$, $X$ expects $Y$ to select a strategy that would do optimally against a $X$ who knows $\theta_F$ (and who plays $\theta_X = \theta_F$). So $X$ is led to look for a 'best' strategy among those that moves in the direction $\theta_F$ (and $X$ expects $Y$ to do the same).
Now, from $X$'s perspective, perhaps $Y$ has some knowledge about what is $r_F$. For instance, if $Y$ can also detect $r_F$, then $X$ will never be able to beat $Y$ (since $X$ is ignorant of either $r_F$ or $\theta_F$). $X$ doesn't know, so $X$ can't hope for anything more than to perform optimally against a $Y$ who is maximally ignorant of $r_F$. Hence $X$ assumes that $Y$ only knows this: since $F$ is put somewhere is the unit disk according to the uniform probability measure $(1/\pi) r dr d\theta$, then $\mathrm{Prob}(r_F \le r) = r^2$, i.e., the marginal probability measure on $r \in [0,1]$ is $\rho_F = 2r dr$. ($X$ expects $Y$ to adopt a similar reasoning.)
Here comes the mathematically involved part, which I will only sketch. $X$ imagines $Y$ comparing opposing different strategies (under the assumption $r_F \sim \rho_F$) where $X$ would play $r_X = r$ according to some probability distribution $\rho_X$ on $[0,1]$ and where $Y$ would play $r_Y = r$ according to some probability distribution $\rho_y$ on $[0,1]$. It is complicated to directly compare the performance of a general $\rho_X$ against a general $\rho_Y$, so we make an ansatz: $\rho_Y = \delta_{r_Y}$, the Dirac measure supported at $r = r_Y$, i.e. $Y$ always move to the fixed distance $r_Y$. (Note that the optimal value for $r_Y$ is still unknown.) Without going into the details, one can show that
$$p:= \mathrm{Prob}(\mbox{$X$ beats $Y$}) \le P P' + (1-P)(1-P') $$
where $P := \mathrm{Prob}_{r_X \sim \rho_X}(r_X \le r_Y)$ and $P' := \mathrm{Prob}_{r_F \sim \rho_F}(r_F \le r_Y)$, with equality if(and only if) $\rho_X = \rho_Y (= \delta_{r_Y})$. Note that if $P' = 1/2$ i.e. if $r_Y = 1/\sqrt{2}$ (the median of $\rho_F$), then $p \le 1/2$ regardless of $\rho_X$, but with equality if $\rho_X = \delta_{1/\sqrt{2}}$. Hence, if $Y$ were to take $r_Y = 1/\sqrt{2}$, $X$ couldn't come with a $\rho_X$ that would make $X$ beats $Y$ most of the time. By symmetry, that also means that if $Y$ were to pick any $\rho_Y \neq \delta_{1/\sqrt{2}}$, then $X$ could beat $Y$ with probability $p > 1/2$ by taking $\rho_X = \delta_{1/\sqrt{2}}$. To summarize, $X$ imagines that $Y$ will come to the conclusion that playing $(r_Y, \theta_Y) = (1/\sqrt{2}, \theta_F)$ is $Y$'s optimal strategy. (And $X$ expects  $Y$ to imagine similarly that $X$ will consider playing $(r_X, \theta_X) = (1/\sqrt{2}, \theta_F)$ as optimal.)
Hence, Erin (who actually knows $\theta_F$) really should play $(r_E, \theta_E) = (1/\sqrt{2}, \theta_F)$, as it is the best move againts a Aaron that would happen to know $\theta_F$. Similarly, Aaron (who actually knows $r_F$ but not $\theta_F$) needs to prepare for Erin to play $(1/\sqrt{2}, \theta_F)$ (despite not knowing anything about Erin, but we knowledgeable outsiders know that it will be Erin's actual strategy).
Aaron is maximally ignorant about $\theta_F$: to him, $\theta_F \sim d\theta/2\pi$. Hence regardless of the way that Aaron would select $\theta_A$, the difference $\theta_A - \theta_F$ also follows a uniform probability law $d\theta/2\pi$ (since Aaron's strategy to pick $\theta_A$ is independent from $\theta_F$). For concreteness, suppose Aaron is to always play in a fixed direction. Hence, picking polar coordinates so that $\theta_F = 0$, it is Aaron's fixed direction that becomes the random variable: $\theta_A \sim d\theta/2\pi$. Aaron (who knows $r_F$) thus better pick $r_A$ in a way maximises the length of the interval of those $\theta_A$ that make Aaron closer to the flag than Erin; a simple geometric argument shows that the optimal choice is $r_A = 0$ if $r_F \le r_E/2 = 1/2\sqrt{2}$ (in which case the maximal interval is $\theta_A \in [0, 2\pi]$) and $r_A = \sqrt{r_E(2r_F - r_E)}$ otherwise (in which case the maximal interval is $\theta_A \in [-\phi(r_F), \phi(r_F)]$ where $\phi(r_F) :=  \mathrm{arcsin}(|r_E-r_F|/r_F)$). (In truth, it is $\theta_F$ that belongs to such intervals centred on Aaron's fixed direction.)
Hence, as knowledgeable outsiders, we evaluate that (define for convenience $\phi(r_F) = \pi$ for $r_F \le r_E/2$)
$$ \mathrm{Prob}(\mbox{$A$ beats $E$}) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^1 \int_{-\phi(r_F)}^{\phi(r_F)} r_F  d\theta_F dr_F \approx 0.196 \, .$$
Scenario 2: maximal common public knowledge. Suppose this time that the tournament was advertised so that all contestants know that at every match, one player would be given $r_F$ and the other $\theta_F$. Moreover, for the sake of the scenario, assume the robots have no detection devices; so really all they know is the information given by the organisers at the beginning of the match. For simplicity, let's also assume that everybody knows that Erin plays a fixed distance from the center whenever told $\theta_F$ (Erin might have disclosed this information publically before the tournament).
When Aaron is told $r_F$, he knows that Erin is told $\theta_F$ and vice versa; both Aaron and Erin know that Erin will play $\theta_E = \theta_F$. Both Aaron and Erin also know that Erin will play a fixed $r_E$.
Much as before, Aaron and Erin know that Aaron's best play is $r_A = \sqrt{r_E(2r_F - r_E)}$ (for brevity, we understood this to equal $0$ when $r_F < r_E/2$) for which Aaron beats Erin if $\theta_F - \theta_A \in [-\phi(r_F|r_E), \phi(r_F|r_E)]$ (where $\phi(r_F|r_E) :=  \mathrm{arcsin}(|r_E-r_F|/r_F)$). For a given $r_E$, the probability that Aaron beats Erin is given by:
$$ (\clubsuit) \quad  \mathrm{Prob}(\mbox{$A$ beats $E$}|r_E) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^1 \int_{-\phi(r_F|r_E)}^{\phi(r_F|r_E)} r_F  d\theta_F dr_F \, .$$
Aaron and Erin both know that Erin has chosen $r_E$ to minimise that probability: it turns out that $r_E = r_E^* \approx 0.5013069942$ is the optimal value for Erin*, in which case
$$ \mathrm{Prob}(\mbox{$A$ beats $E$}) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^1 \int_{-\phi(r_F|r_E^*)}^{\phi(r_F|r_E^*)} r_F  d\theta_F dr_F \approx 0.16618649 \, .$$
*To obtain this result, one calculates first that for the integral in ($\clubsuit$) is not minimised by $r_E = 0$ or $r_E = 1$ (since $r_E = 1/\sqrt{2}$ does better). Hence $r_E^*$ is a value where the derivative of the integral from ($\clubsuit$) with respect to $r_E$ equals $0$; this derivative is
$$ \frac{r_E}{4} + \frac{2}{\pi} \left( \int_{r_E/2}^{r_E} \dfrac{dr_F}{\sqrt{1-((r_E/r_F)-1)^2}} -   \int_{r_E}^{1} \dfrac{dr_F}{\sqrt{1-(1-(r_E/r_F))^2}}  \right)$$
After the changes of variables $v = r_E/r_F$ and $z = v-1$, this becomes
\begin{align} & \frac{r_E}{4} + \frac{2r_E}{\pi} \left( \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{dz}{(z+1)^2 \sqrt{1-z^2}} -   \int_{r_E- 1}^{0} \dfrac{dz}{(z+1)^2 \sqrt{1-z^2}}  \right) \\
&= \frac{r_E}{4} + \frac{2r_E}{\pi} \left( \frac{2}{3} -   \int_{r_E- 1}^{0} \dfrac{dz}{(z+1)^2 \sqrt{1-z^2}}  \right).
\end{align}
Since we know $0 < r_E^* < 1$, we need to solve
$$ (\spadesuit) \quad \int_{r^*_E- 1}^{0} \dfrac{dz}{(z+1)^2 \sqrt{1-z^2}} = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{\pi}{8}.$$
Since the integrand on the LHS is positive over $z \in (-1, 0]$, this equation has a unique solution, which I manually (with WolframAlpha) found to be approximately equal to $r_E^* \approx 0.5013$. (In fact, the integral in ($\spadesuit$) has a relatively simple primitive, and by elementary manipulations, one shows that $r_E^*$ solves an explicit cubic equation.) Putting this back into ($\clubsuit$) yields $\mathrm{Prob}(\mbox{$A$ beats $E$}) \approx 0.1662$.
(In my initial answer, a calculation mistake in derivating the boundary term $r_E/2$ in ($\clubsuit$) led to the disappearance of the first term $r_E/4$ in the formula for the derivative, and thus of $\pi/8$ in ($\spadesuit$), thereby leading to an overestimation of $r_E^*$ and, with it, of $\mathrm{Prob}(\mbox{$A$ beats $E$})$. As everyone can verify, solving ($\spadesuit$) without the $\pi/8$ term yields the $r_E^* \approx 0.608$ and the probability that Aaron beats Erin of $\approx 17.4 \%$ that I claimed initially.)

Hello, thank you for your precise answer. Could you please explain how you came up with (|):=arcsin(|−|/) ? I applied the law of cosines and ended up with an arccos, yielding a different result from yours.

@Julien (1/2) Much as in the longest answer of math kuma, given $r_F$ and $r_E$, Aaron needs to play within the disc $D$ of radius $|r_E - r_F|$ centred on $Q = (r_F, \theta_F)$. Denoting by $C_{r_A}$ the circle of radius $r_A$ centred at $O$, the optimal radius  $r_A$ to play is the one maximising the 'angular width' $2 \phi$ (at $O$) of the intersection $C_{r_A} \cap D$. However, the 'angular width' (at $O$) of $D$ itself is $2 \phi(r_F|r_E)$, namely the angle at $O$ between the two tangents lines from $O$ to $\partial D$.

@Julien (2/2)  If $P$ denotes the point of tangency between the first line and $\partial D$ and $Q$ denotes the center of $D$ (the point where $E$ moves her robot), then $OPQ$ is a right triangle (right at $P$) with hypotenuse $OQ = r_F$ and $PQ = |r_E - r_F|$, so that $\sin(\phi(r_F|r_E)) = |r_E - r_F|/r_F$. Hence the optimal $r_F$ is $r_F = |OP| = \sqrt{r_F^2 - |r_E - r_F|^2} = \sqrt{r_E(2r_F-r_E)}$, so that $\phi = \phi(r_F|r_E) = \mathrm{arcsin}(|r_E - r_F|/r_F)$.

@JordanPayette I have it on good authority that your $r_E^$ is a bit too high, the solution starts with 0.16. Could you provide your derivation of $r_E^$?

@Hans-PeterSchrei Thanks for the info! Indeed, I had made a mistake in my calculations; I edited my answer to provide a bit more information on my method, which indeed yields $\mathrm{Prob}(\mbox{$A$ beats $E$}) \approx 0.1662$. By the way, should we understand on good authority that Scenario 2 is the intended one? ;-)

@JordanPayette Yes, that is correct.
